# why operator overloading is necessary in c#

Tags: c#

```
class MyNumber
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

I don't understood why the below code will throw error.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyNumber firstNumber = new MyNumber();
        MyNumber secondNumber = new MyNumber();

        firstNumber.Number = 10;
        secondNumber.Number = 5;

        MyNumber sum = firstNumber + secondNumber; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Because compiler does not know how to handle the `+` operation on your custom type unless you specify that, implementing the operator.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no `+` operator defined for MyNumber this means that you get a syntax error when you try to use it, instead you probably want something like this:

```
class MyNumber
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public static MyNumber operator +(MyNumber c1, MyNumber c2) 
    {
        //sum the .Number components and return them as a new MyNumber
        return new MyNumber{ Number = c1.Number + c2.Number };
    }
}
```

What this does is explain what `+` means in the context of your MyNumber class

Answer (score 4):

Each of these addition operators yields different results based on the type it is used against.

```
string s = "Foo" + "Bar"; //Resulting in FooBar
int i = 1 + 3; //Resulting in 4
```

Now for your custom class, how do you expect the operator to function if you dont tell it what to do?

Comment: Exactly! The original question really is, "Why should I have to program my program?"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really simple the compiler does not know how to handle those operation for your custom type.
The example quoted by you is simple, and you want, when I say add `+` then add the properties with the same name but lets take another example Multiplication`*` for a basic Complex number class you have already studied and we know multiplication for Complex number class is,

> (a + *i* b) * (c + *i* d) = ac -bd + *i* (bc + ad)

do you think so compiler has a magic trick and he knows this is complex number class and multiplication is to be carried like this, Surely it does not know for that you need to tell it this way you have to carry out operation, **that's why operator overloading is needed** and of course if you don't overload you get exception in Error list stating

> Error  1 Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ConsoleApplicationTest.Class1' and 'ConsoleApplicationTest.Class1'

So for complex class implementation will be like this,

```
    public class Complex
    {
        public int real;
        public int imaginary;

        public Complex(int real, int imaginary)
        {
            this.real = real;
            this.imaginary = imaginary;
        }

        public static Complex operator *(Complex c1, Complex c2)
        {
            return new Complex(c1.real * c2.real - c1.imaginary * c2.imaginary, c1.imaginary * c2.real + c1.real * c2.imaginary);
        }            
    }
```